# Is there a way I can add multiple data sources to ListView?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Currently, I am trying to make a table, which retrieves failed products and passed products from an Entity with LINQ.

Lets assume I've done that, but have 2 lists, A regular List(Of String), and a SortedDictionary(Of String, int32) (To hold the product, and the number of times the testpoint has failed).

Now, when I want to output them to ListView, in a Webform, how can I make it, so that List(Of String), will be output on the listview, and the SortedDictionary, be output after the List(Of String)?

Thank you.

EDIT: Although I could just add the SortedDictionary values to the end of the List aswell, but how would I go around doing so? Because I will create a listview with 2 columns, one which holds the descriptive text, and then a List(Of String) value. And the SortedDictionary would follow, requiring two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 
You can try to aggregate all data in one source and to add it to ListView.

Comment: Okay, I'll most likely use Dictionary to store the table text and then add SortedDictionary to end of that. Thank you